# Vue 2 Input not updating with leading zeors

Tags: vue.js, leading-zero, vue-reactivity

I'm trying to get rid of these leading zeros. I have a method that gets called on input, the emits it's own input:

```
handleInput: function (value) {
            const newValue = String(parseInt(value));
            this.$emit('input', newValue);
        }
```

When I inspect the code, I do see that the value reflects this change through the props:

[image: Leading zeros, but input not being updated]

But looking at the actual input itself, the leading zeros still remain. I'm starting to suspect that its' because:

```
00000000000000123 === 123
```

I only think this because the only time it actually updates the input is when I change the numbers after the zero:

[image: Leading zeros go away after number updates]

And the actual input element won't update. But I quite frankly don't even know what to Google for this one. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<template>
    <input :value="local_value" type="text" v-on:input="handleInput" v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
<script>

export default {
    props: {
        value: {
            type: [String, Number],
            default: "",
        }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            local_value: 0,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleInput: function (value) {
            const newValue = String(parseInt(value.target.value));
            this.$set(this, 'local_value', newValue);
            this.$emit('input', newValue);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: remove the parseInt, treat it as a string, if you need to validate, then do it some other way https://playcode.io/823851/

Comment: Internally, the number is 123, but the user sees 000000123. My goal is to have the user see what it actually is.

Comment: cast it on change/input, then the user sees what the value is, see link now

Comment: Oh man, the v-model worked, I didn't have it set to v-model. I thought v-model just added the value props and input listener for you. IDK how to set your answer as the right one, do you mind writing up an answer explaining why mine didn't work but using v-model + input listner did? I'd be very curious to see why: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Of course, no pressure. I can answer the question myself after some more research and credit you in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still emit that as a number then you can solve that by doing the below

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

and then in the methods

```
methods: {
        handleInput: function (val) {
            // Removed the parseInt line
            this.$set(this, 'local_value', val.target.value);
            this.$emit('input', val.target.value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do it. After changing the type tel, and adding the pattern, it still lets me add the leading zeros. I'm wondering if there's a technique that masking components use that I should be looking at?

Comment: oh so what's your requirement,  you don't want it to let you type zeros?

Comment: Yes, and I apologize for not making that more clear. I'll update the question.

Comment: no leading zeros. One zero is okay.

Comment: use regex then!

Comment: The issue wasn't with the method to remove zeros, it was actually doing it. The issue was that the data value would change but the value that was being displayed wasn't changing :(